# jQuery Ajax for ASP.NET .ascx control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am making an AJAX call using jQuery to an .ascx control's method in the code behind to get a list of business objects:

**C# Code:**

```
if (Request.Headers["X-OFFICIAL-REQUEST"] == "TRUE") ReturnList(Request.Params[1]);

  protected void ReturnList(string param)
  {
    Response.Write(GetBusinesses(param));
    Response.Flush();
    try {  
         Response.Close(); 
        }
    catch { }
    Response.End();
    return;
  } 

private string GetBusinesses(string classificationName)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(classificationName))
    {
        dSourse = BusinessesDBService.Instance.GetLatestListingsUpdates(classificationName).ToList();
        jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    }
    return jSearializer.Serialize(dSourse);

}
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
window.jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: location.href,
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({ 'FUNCTION': 'ReturnList', 'param0': classificationName.toLowerCase() }),
    success: function (data) {
        data = eval(data);

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OFFICIAL-REQUEST", "TRUE"); //Used to ID as a AJAX Request
    },
    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
     //build HTML
        var tablestring = '<table ><tr><td>UsreID" + "</td><td>UserName</td></tr>';

        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
            tablestring = tablestring + "<tr>";
            tablestring = tablestring + "<td>" +
                data[i].BusinessID + "</td>";
            tablestring = tablestring + "<td>" +
                data[i].BusinessName + "</td>";
            tablestring = tablestring + "</tr>";
        }
        tablestring = tablestring + "</table>";
        var divResult = document.getElementById("divAjax");
        divResult.innerHTML = tablestring;

    }
});
```

The http call is executed fine and the collection is serialized and returned with the response however I have a few problems here. The main one is that the HTML is not being created - I am not able to capture the string returned. The string below shows up in the Firebug script window after the call is complete

[{"BusinessID":6549,"BusinessName":"Ivory Store","IsMain":true},    {"BusinessID":16565,"BusinessName":"Classic Nails","IsMain"},{"BusinessID":5877,"BusinessName":"Visible Changes Hair","IsMain":true}]

Also in the Firebug I have noticed that string in XMLHttpRequest response object and the error message is "JSON is not valid"   Any suggetions? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you ever have trouble with invalid JSON and can't find the problem, I suggest you use a validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason the code-behind C# parser code below was not appending "]" to the end of the string so I had to append it manually - it worked!!! Thank you.

```
   public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        string retVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        return retVal + "]";
    }
```

Comment: Try 'Flushing' the MemoryStream. If it wasn't actually appending the trailing ']' that would be a significant bug in the framework and several others would have similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

that is NOT valid JSON

```
 [{"BusinessID":6549,"BusinessName":"Ivory Store","IsMain":true}, {"BusinessID":16565,"BusinessName":"Classic Nails","IsMain"},{"BusinessID":5877,"BusinessName":"Visible Changes Hair","IsMain":true}]
```

SEE the missing part on the middle "IsMain" likely needs either

```
 [{"BusinessID":6549,"BusinessName":"Ivory Store","IsMain":true}, {"BusinessID":16565,"BusinessName":"Classic Nails","IsMain":true},{"BusinessID":5877,"BusinessName":"Visible Changes Hair","IsMain":true}]
```

OR

```
 [{"BusinessID":6549,"BusinessName":"Ivory Store","IsMain":true}, {"BusinessID":16565,"BusinessName":"Classic Nails","IsMain":false},{"BusinessID":5877,"BusinessName":"Visible Changes Hair","IsMain":true}]
```

See this page: click the JSLint button: http://jsfiddle.net/QmMdC/

Comment: My bad, the "missing part" on IsMain is ok, I lost the "true" piece when truncating the actual JSON - about 30 fields. I will post the entire object's JSON tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason the code-behind C# parser code below was not appending "]" to the end of the string so I had to append it manually - it worked!!! Thank you.  public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            string retVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            return retVal + "]";
        }

Comment: Yes, I saw your c# code and it is definatly NOT the way I do it, giving a class and letting the framework handle the serialization of that class seems to be the way to do on this..